# noticed a process in linux which isn't shown in process list hows that happen?

Tags: c, linux, unix, libc

i have recently noticed  a hidden process  it isn't  appearing in process list, but its consuming cpu time and memory.how does this happen , how is it written , whats the job its doing , how can we kill that process.

**`Is There any way to unhide such process which are hidden`**

Comment: Back in the good old days, malware authors worked this stuff out for themselves

Comment: By definition, process that hide from view are malware

Comment: It depends on the OS: process namespaces (linux) or jails (BSD) or similar can give processes a different view of the pid namespace or create multiple nested namespaces.

Answer (score 6):

In short, you can only do this with kernel level code. Either you'll have to modify your kernel from source, or write an application which has so many security vulnerabilities that it would not run on a modern OS unless you intentionally crippled existing security features of the OS itself.

If this pursuit is academic, then the link below should provide more assistance. If you are attempting to do something malicious, note that this approach will fail.

Finally, you should be aware that there is no valid or legitimate use case for this kind of process, save for some sort of draconian DRM mechanism that cripples the OS somehow, or maybe intentionally hiding processes owned by a certain user/group that handle important device drivers that even the ROOT user shouldn't attempt to slay/terminate/kill. On seLinux, QNX, or something that would go into a mission critical system with administrative user access, it would likely be to prevent rookie/newbie admins from shooting themselves in the foot.

Credits:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17164/how-to-make-a-process-invisible-to-other-users